# Iterate through laravel result object

Tags: laravel, loops

My Code is like below.

```php
$prayers = Prayer_time::where('mosque_id', $request->mosque_id)
    ->where('month', $month)
    ->where('date', $date)
    ->first();

foreach ($prayers as $key => $prayer) {
    if ($prayer != null) {
        $payer_times[$key] = $prayer;
    }
}

return response()->json(['prayer_times' => $payer_times], 200);
```

I am getting below output.

```json
{
    "prayer_times": {
        "incrementing": true,
        "exists": true,
        "timestamps": true
    }
}
```

How can I iterate through result?

Comment: Convert your `$prayers` object to an array, _then_ iterate it: `foreach($prayers->toArray() as $key => $value)`

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis. Your solution is working. How do I know I reach the last element of the array when iterating here ?

Comment: When you exit the loop? You've got an associative array, like `['id' => 137, 'mosque_id' => 1, /* ... */]`, so there isn't really a last element here; why do you need that?

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis. I would like to attach another value after the last element. Thanks.

Comment: So after the `foreach()` loop, just do `$prayer_times['newValue'] = 'whatever';` (or similar); you don't need to do that in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that first one is an API Controller and you want to iterate over the `prayer_times` in a frontend

```
res.data.prayers_time.each({
    DO WHATEVER
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Ajaz Ul Haq. I would like to iterate in Controller. Thanks